# Get count based on value bash

Tags: json, bash, shell, awk, jq

I have data in this format in a file:

```
{"field1":249449,"field2":116895,"field3":1,"field4":"apple","field5":42,"field6":"2019-07-01T00:00:10","metadata":"","frontend":""}
{"field1":249448,"field2":116895,"field3":1,"field4":"apple","field5":42,"field6":"2019-07-01T00:00:10","metadata":"","frontend":""}
{"field1":249447,"field2":116895,"field3":1,"field4":"apple","field5":42,"field6":"2019-07-01T00:00:10","metadata":"","frontend":""}
{"field1":249443,"field2":116895,"field3":1,"field4":"apple","field5":42,"field6":"2019-07-01T00:00:10","metadata":"","frontend":""}
{"field1":249449,"field2":116895,"field3":1,"field4":"apple","field5":42,"field6":"2019-07-01T00:00:10","metadata":"","frontend":""}
```

Here, each entry represents a row. I want to have a count of the rows with respect to the value in field one, like:

```
249449 : 2
249448 : 1
249447 : 1
249443 : 1
```

How can I get that?

Comment: Why is 2 assigned to 249448 and 0 to 249443? This is not a count.

Comment: That was just an example. It should be:
249449: 2
249448: 1
249447: 1
249443: 1

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. Given your tags, I'd expect to see bash and awk code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `awk`

```
$ awk -F'[,:]' -v OFS=' : ' '{a[$2]++} END{for(k in a) print k, a[k]}' file
```

Comment: Should be `$2` fixed.

Comment: I ^’d you because it is the best solution (IMO)... — just wanted to suggest -v OFS=‘ : ‘ and in the final print statement do: print k, a[k] — think it would look cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) command line tool to interpret JSON data. `uniq -c` counts the number of occurences.

```
% jq .field1 < $INPUTFILE | sort | uniq -c
      1 249443
      1 249447
      1 249448
      2 249449
```

(tested with `jq 1.5-1-a5b5cbe` on linux xubuntu 18.04 with zsh)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an efficient `jq`-only solution:

```
reduce inputs.field1 as $x ({}; .[$x|tostring] += 1)
| to_entries[]
| "\(.key) : \(.value)"
```

Invocation: `jq -nrf program.jq input.json`

(Note in particular the `-n` option.)

Of course if an object-representation of the counts is satisfactory, then
one could simply write:

```
jq -n 'reduce inputs.field1 as $x ({}; .[$x|tostring] += 1)' input.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) and some shell utils, change the non-data delimiters to squeezed tabs, count field 3, (it'd be field 2, but there's a leading tab), reverse, then pretty print as per *OP* spec:

```
tr -s '{":,}' '\t' < file | datamash -sg 3 count 3 | tac | xargs printf '%s : %s\n'
```

Output:

```
249449 : 2
249448 : 1
249447 : 1
249443 : 1
```